# Merging a color into a bitmap using c# (universal windows application)

Tags: c#

I have a .png resource that includes areas that need to be "colored" as described in the table below (these are my own definitions, if there are better terms that I should use feel free to educate me). I need to "color" this image based on a ColorBrush (e.g. BGRA=#6572D8FF) such that ...

```
//                        Input            Output
//    Transparent  BGRA=#FFFFFF00 --> #FFFFFF00
//    AlphaOnly    BGRA=#00000000 --> #6572D800   // Colored area
//    Alpha-Shaded BGRA=#000000aa --> #6572D8aa   // Colored area
//    Solid colors BGRA=#bbggrrFF --> #rrggbbFF
```

The resultant image needs to be displayed using the following XAML ...

```
    <Viewbox Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
        <Grid Height="100" Width="100">
            <Image x:Name="currentImage" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Placing the control onto a red background and specifying a blue ColorBrush, I was hoping to get the bottom image (which I created by simply putting a blue ellipse behind the original image)

[image]

Unfortunately I get the top image. My transparency is lost and the alpha shading I was hoping to achieve is wrong. Any help (including you "idiot", you should do this like this) would be greatly appreciated.

```
public sealed class MyImage : Control {
    public MyImage() {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyImage);
        Loaded += MyImage_Loaded;
    }
    private async void MyImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ((Image)this.GetTemplateChild("currentImage")).Source = await ColorImage();
    }
    private async Task<WriteableBitmap> ColorImage() {
        // Get the image as a byte array
        StorageFile fileImage = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(BaseImageUri, UriKind.Absolute));
        ImageProperties propsImage = await fileImage.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
        int height = (int)propsImage.Height;
        int width = (int)propsImage.Width;
        byte[] baseImagePixels = await ReadPixels(fileImage);

        // Modify the mask by adding the accent color
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                byte B = baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 0];
                byte G = baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 1];
                byte R = baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 2];
                byte A = baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 3];
                if (R == 0x00 && G == 0x00 && B == 0x00 && A != 0xFF) {
                    baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 0] = ColorBrush.Color.B;
                    baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 1] = ColorBrush.Color.G;
                    baseImagePixels[4 * (y * height + x) + 2] = ColorBrush.Color.R;
                }
            }
        }
        WriteableBitmap coloredImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)propsImage.Width, (int)propsImage.Height);
        using (Stream stream = coloredImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream()) {
            await stream.WriteAsync(baseImagePixels, 0, baseImagePixels.Length);
        }
        return coloredImage;
    }
    private async Task<byte[]> ReadPixels(StorageFile file) {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
        BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform();
        PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            new BitmapTransform(),
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
        return pixelData.DetachPixelData();
    }
    public String BaseImageUri {
        get { return (String)GetValue(BaseImageUriProperty); }
        set {
            if (value.StartsWith("ms-appx:///")) {
                SetValue(BaseImageUriProperty, value);
            } else {
                SetValue(BaseImageUriProperty, "ms-appx:///" + value);
            }
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BaseImageUriProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BaseImageUri", typeof(String), typeof(MyImage), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorBrushProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(MyImage), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Comment: BTW the reason I cannot just put the color I want behind the image is because I don't know what parts of the image will be transparent or shaded (i.e. I don't know that it is a circle)

Comment: `y * height` should be `y * width` (though obviously in a square bitmap it won't matter). As for the problem, are you sure of the pixel format? Have you tried switching the order of the bytes, e.g. reading/writing A from `+ 0` and B from/to `+ 3`? Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to know for sure what's wrong, if for no other reason than that it's just too much hassle to bother trying to reproduce the problem and actually check the code.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the height/width thing - that would have driven me nuts later when I tried a non-square image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [*premultiplied alpha*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx) issue to me, but that's just a wild guess.

Some graphic libraries require that pixels with alpha < 1.0 store their RGB components as:

```
R' := R x A
G' := G x A
B' := B x A
A' := A
```

Hence RGB → `0xFFFFFF` with zero alpha would be invalid.

Blending algorithms which expect to be fed with premultiplied alpha pixels produce unexpected results when their RGB values exceed their *alpha*.

So fully transparent pixels are always encoded as `0x000000` with 0 alpha in a premultiplied alpha case.

Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Alpha compositing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx):

> Assuming that the pixel color is expressed using straight (non-premultiplied) RGBA tuples, a pixel value of (0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5) implies a pixel that has 50% of the maximum green intensity and 50% opacity. If the color were fully green, its RGBA would be (0, 1, 0, 0.5).
>
> However, if this pixel uses premultiplied alpha, all of the RGB values (0, 1, 0) are multiplied by 0.5 and then the alpha is appended to the end to yield (0, 0.5, 0, 0.5). In this case, the 0.5 value for the G channel actually indicates 100% green intensity (with 50% opacity). For this reason, knowing whether a file uses premultiplied or straight alpha is essential to correctly process or composite it.

It also provides an explanation of how the various color merging operators work.

Comment: This is great information and it make perfect sense because in the section where I set the pixels to a specific color the Alpha value is always 255 (or 100%). When I get chance I will play around with this some more. Thanks! PS: I cannot vote you up because I don't have any reputation yet - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution. I have no idea why it works though ... would love to be educated on that if somebody knows why. I added a second change to the for loops.

```
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int pixelIndex = 4 * (y * width + x);
                byte B = baseImagePixels[pixelIndex];
                byte G = baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 1];
                byte R = baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 2];
                byte A = baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 3];
                if (!(B == 0xFF && G == 0xFF && R == 0xFF && A == 0x00)) {
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex] = colorBrush.Color.B;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 1] = colorBrush.Color.G;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 2] = colorBrush.Color.R;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 3] = colorBrush.Color.A;
                } else if (B == 0xFF && G == 0xFF && R == 0xFF && A == 0x00) {
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex] = 0x00;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 1] = 0x00;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 2] = 0x00;
                    baseImagePixels[pixelIndex + 3] = 0x00;
                }
            }
        }
```